# Gratis alternative to KernelCare

Tags: gratis, linux, centos

I'm looking for a gratis (preferable open source) alternative to [KernelCare](https://cloudlinux.com/all-products/product-overview/kernelcare). KernelCare allows Linux operating systems to perform kernel updates without having to reboot the system itself. This provides no downtime on the server (having no websites down for any period of time is always wonderful) and also has security benefits (not having an old kernel for that long of a period of time). I would like the package to meet the following requirements:

- Compatible with CentOS 7
- Updates Kernal without having to reboot

Preferably it would also update the kernel automatically. This would be used on a production level server environment, it should be somewhat well-known and trusted.

Comment: Without duplicating the question, I'd like to have that for Debian as well. So if a solution matches both systems, please point that out in your answers :)